Multiple checkbox's with multiple dropdowns and input tags, store selected values together/remove if unchecked
Lets say I have multiple checkbox's and some text and then a dropdown from 1-10 in the following format
[CHECKBOX1]   [NAME1]    [DROPDOWN1 1-10]

[CHECKBOX2]   [NAME2]    [DROPDOWN2 1-10]

[CHECKBOX3]   [NAME3]    [DROPDOWN3 1-10]

.....

[CHECKBOXN]   [NAMEN]    [DROPDOWNN 1-10]

I know I can capture the checked values into an array like the following
arr.push(document.querySelector('.messageCheckbox').checked); 

and similar I can do it for NAME1,and the :selected option for the values 1-10.
However how do I map each rows values to each other? So if I checkbox1 I will push the typed in Name1, selected dropdown1 ( from 1-10) into one item into an array? Similar say for N checkbox's. I will hope to get some data in the end like
IF 3 CHECKEDBOXS are CHECKED: {{BOB,2} , {SARAH,5}, {LILY,5}}

Similarly if i uncheck a box, those items would be removed from this array

@MisterJojo could you give an example in this case please

You mention "array" in your question, but then you show your desired results, which is an "object".

@ScottMarcus sorry yes an object is what I meant.

Your expectation of results that look like this:
{{BOB,2} , {SARAH,5}, {LILY,5}} is wrong. Objects separate keys from values with :, not ,. Also, if you don't have a particular need to have the results stored as objects within a parent object, you can just go with one object that has a key to represent each row of data.
In my solution below, I start by wrapping all the rows of inputs in a common parent "wrapper". This allows for "event delegation", where any click within that wrapper will bubble up and be handled at the wrapper level instead of setting up events for each checkbox.
Then, within the handler, we check to ensure that it's only checkbox clicks we're responding to.
Then, we determine if we are adding to the results object or removing from it.
In each branch of the if statement, we then either add the values from that row's textbox and select or remove the existing key from the results object.


// Set up object to hold the data
let results = {};

// Set up event delegation on the wrapper div
document.querySelector("#wrapper").addEventListener("change", function(event){
  // Only react to checkbox checks/unchecks
  if(event.target.type === "checkbox"){
    // Add or remove?
    if(event.target.checked){  
      results[event.target.nextElementSibling.value] = 
        event.target.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.value;
    } else {
      delete results[event.target.nextElementSibling.value];
    }
  }
  console.clear();
  console.log(results);
});
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input>
    <select>
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option>5</option>
      <option>6</option>
      <option>7</option>
      <option>8</option>
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>




Good example, I noticed that you have to click the checkbox in order for it to update the object entry. Is there anyway to change this on the fly if the checkbox stays checked and you change the text or option? If you uncheck it, it will .pop of course.
